# Total Commander FTP can't connect after network adapter reset

Tags: networking, virtualbox, total-commander

Every time I install Oracle VirtualBox (that reinstalls its network adapter so the Internet connection gets disabled for a split second), my Total Commander looses the ability to connect via FTP. I initiate the FTP and it connects to the ftp server and when it tries to list the directories, it just stops and nothing happens. 
It hits the following line:

*150 Opening data channel for directory list.*

*Downloading*

What is preventing TC from showing the list?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I change the connection to **Passive mode**, it works in these cases. I still don't know why it doesn't work in *active mode*.